# Shortcut Icon disappears when Target points to invalid path (Windows XP)

Tags: windows-xp, shortcut

START

[image]

1. The path to the Icon is valid (Ex. "C:\MyIcon.ico")
2. The path to the Target was valid (Ex. "N:\My Folder\MyApp.exe")
3. I did not touch the shortcut file at all
4. I renamed the folder on the file system (Ex. "N:\My Folder2\MyApp.exe")
5. Icon disappears (see below)

[image]

END

*The same situation does not cause icon to disappear on Windows 7.  This is a problem because the target in on a network drive, and when user is not connected to network, or VPN, the icon disappears, even if the icon file is stored and referenced locally.*

**Is this just a problem with Windows XP?  Or is there anything that I can do to avoid the icon disappearing when disconnected from network?**

Comment: Try http://superuser.com

Comment: I'm creating the shortcuts programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done extensive testing, and I believe that it's by design in Windows XP to make shortcut icons disappear when the target of the shortcut is invalid.

When the target becomes invalid again, the icon reappears.